# List git repositories with unpushed changes

Tags: git, bash, debian, debian-based

I'm reinstalling my OS. I have thousands of repos on my computer. I have a feeling that I've made a few changes in some repos while hacking around that are not committed and/or pushed.

From a bash shell on my Debian PC, what's the best way to find a list of changes that have not yet been committed/pushed to their remotes, and decide whether or not I want to keep the changes?

Comment: What about uncommitted changes?

Comment: Sorry for the silly comment, but hi Greg. First time I realize 2 people can have the same SO name.

Answer (score 5):

You may like the project multi-git-status from Ferry Boender.

https://github.com/fboender/multi-git-status.
"Show uncommited, untracked and unpushed changes in multiple Git repositories."

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming finding each repo and running `git status` in each repo is sufficient for your needs.  In which case the following might be a starting point for you:

```
find / -name "*.git" -type d -print0 | xargs -0 -L 1 -i% bash -c "cd %/..; pwd; git status -s -uno"
```

`find` traverses your filesystem, starting at `/` (you may want to restrict that to perhaps `~`), searching for .git diretories.  The output (null-delimited to handle funny filenames) is piped to xargs, which `cd`s to each repo, prints the `pwd`, and short-form git-status, without listing untracked files.

Answer (score 2):

The previous answer finds uncommitted, but not unpushed commits.

This will find both:

`find / -name "*.git" -type d -print0 | xargs -0 -L 1 -i% bash -c "cd %/..; pwd; git status -s -uno; git cherry -v 2>/dev/null"`

`git cherry` shows the SHA1 of unpushed changes; `-v` adds the commit comment; and error redirection suppresses noisy output for repos that lack an upstream.

Comment: on Mac (using zsh) a lowercase -i throws "xargs: illegal option -- i"; using capital I works: `xargs -0 -L 1 -I% bash -c`

Answer (score 1):

### Be sure you check all branches

Unpushed changes can exist in branches other than the checked-out branch. There can also be more than one upstream per branch.

### Zero in on relevant info

This approach takes its lead from other answers, which are very helpful starting points, and subs out a few details.

```
find / -name "*.git" -type d -print0 | xargs -0 -L 1 -I% sh -c "cd %/..; pwd; git status -suno; git branch -vvv 2>/dev/null" > local_repos.txt
```

The above one-liner writes to a file called local_repos.txt, which is the easiest way to read the output. It

- lists all branches, marking the checked-out branch with an asterisk
- clarifies when repo HEAD is detached
- shows tracked files with uncommitted changes
- distinguishes which branches have upstreams and which do not
- counts the commits of each branch that is ahead/behind its upstreams
- gives the most recent sha & commit message on each branch

Like the other solutions, it also lists the path to each repo. Unlike the other solutions, it does not break out a list of references to unpushed commits on the checked-out branch.

### Example output

```
/dir-with-repo-1
    main  d96c7fcd [origin/main: behind 3] update abcd
  * staging f938e4aa [origin/staging: ahead 2, behind 6] tweak workspace layout
/dir-with-repo-2
  * dev   8b9cec2b [origin/dev] Merge branch 'feature/35-featurename' into 'dev'
    main  b96d6fcd [origin/main: behind 4] update efgh
/dir-with-repo-3
  * hotfix  239f95dc [origin/hotfix] update ijkl
    main    4c92eaa7 [origin/main: behind 7] update klmn
/dir-with-repo-4
  M composer.json
  M composer.lock
  * main 0d2050c add opqr
/dir-with-repo-5
  * (HEAD detached at d3286d57) d3286d57 fix(FunctionComment): Add support for hijk
    1.2.3                       d3286d57 [origin/1.2.3] Add support for hijk
```